# How to create alarm on number of EventBridge Rules breaching a certain threshold?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge, cloudwatch-alarms

I have a system that auto creates and deletes CloudWatch Rules but there is a hard limit of 300 rules in every Event Bus. I want to create an alarm that gets triggered whenever a certain number, say 100, is reached. How can I do that using CDK code?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Lambda function that calls the [ListRules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_ListRules.html) API.  The Lambda counts the rules.  Have EventBridge [trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events_targets.LambdaFunction.html) the Lambda periodically with a scheduled [Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events.Rule.html#schedule).  If you want an Alarm, your Lambda could write the rule count to CloudWatch as a [custom metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html) and configure an [Alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudwatch.Alarm.html) to monitor it. A simpler option is to have the Lambda put an SNS notification to a [Topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_sns.Topic.html) if the rule count exceeds 100.

To recap, the CDK constructs would be: a Lambda `Function`, an EventBridge `Rule` and a CloudWatch `Alarm` (or SNS `Topic` and `Subscription`).